# Hay alguna forma de aplicarle un "match_parent" al LinearLayout dentro del ScrollView?

Tags: android, android-studio

Tengo este codigo y necesito que el ImageView este pegado en la parte inferior

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="#000"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <ImageView
                android:background="#BF000000"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher_foreground"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="50dp"/>
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Puedo agregar mas elementos pero no quedaria el mismo formato para todos los dispositivos

Comment: no entiendo tu pregunta¿ podrias ser mas especifico?  ¿quieres que el Imageview quede fijo en la parte inferior del activity?¿quieres que el imageview se coloque  siempre en la parte inferior del scrollview a pesar de desplazar las barras de scroll vertical? ¿ o simplemente quieres colocar contenido en el scrollview y que la imagen sea el ultimo elemento del scrollview? un consejo , si te da problemas el match_parent del linearlayout, coloca la propiedad android:fillViewport="true" en el scrollview y en el linerlayout android:layout_weight="1"

Comment: Necesito que al ImageView  sea el ultimo elemento visible, osea que este pegado al borde inferior,  pero al mismo tiempo que si hay mas elementos debajo y haces scroll este se mueva a la par

Comment: ¿ que sea el ultimo elemento visible cuando arranca el activity? es decir ¿que nunca quede oculto cuando arranca la pantalla o activity?, pregunta, ..¿.los elementos del scrollview seran fijos, es decir ya estaran colocados en el código de la aplicación  o se cargaran de forma dinamica cada vez que se cargue la pantalla?

Answer (score 1):

Claro, que puedes agregarle. En muchas ocasiones queremos que nuestro LinearLayout que esta dentro de un scrollview tenga un match_parent, pero la forma de realizar es utilizando el atributo `android:fillViewPort="true"`, según la documentación este parámetro nos permite:

> Define si la vista de desplazamiento debe extender su contenido para llenar la ventana gráfica.

Entonces el quedaria asi:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:fillViewPort="true"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#000"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <ImageView
            android:background="#BF000000"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher_foreground"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="50dp"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Cabe mencionar que ya con esto no es necesario ponerle match_parent, bastan con ponerle wrap_content, pero se comportara como si fuera un match_parent

Espero te ayude :)

Answer (score 0):

Entiendo lo que quieres hacer Hermenino Leal!, no conozco una forma de hacerlo desde el XML, pero desde código lo puedes hacer así:

```
final ScrollView scrollView = (ScrollView) findViewById(R.id.scroll_view);
final ImageView imagen = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.mover_imagen);
scrollView.post(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        scrollView.smoothScrollTo(0, imagen.getBottom() - scrollView.getHeight());
    }
});
```

Comment: la verdad es que no si si sera esto u otra cosa lo que busca, el problema que le puede surgir con este metodo , dependiendo de los elementos que hay dentro del scrollview y de la pantalla del dispositivo, es que el contenido que este al principio del scroll quede oculto...